# Converting sentences from active to passive voice

Tags: active-voice

> **A**: I am dancing in the party.
>
> **B**: I am jumping into the river with friends.

I have a little bit confusion about the 'active and passive' forms of a sentence. Can we make the passive of above mentioned sentences? As far as I am concerned, we don't make the passive of "Intransitive verbs". So, kindly, share your views.

Comment: Only *transitive* verbs can be formed into a true passive construction.  We would have to say "The party was danced *at*" or "The river was jumped *into*".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, any way to say that without a dangling preposition?  :-)

Comment: Not in English.

Comment: Well, "ambitansitive verb". It can be used transitively or intransitively. According to context ; it is used as an intransitive verb. HOWEVER, I am bewildered whether we can have a method to change intransitive verbs into passive or not!

Comment: @fixer1234 "The party was danced at by us" and "The river was jumped into by us"... but that inserts the subject back into the sentence. So *technically* yes, but for the purpose of this question, no.

Comment: The OP is right; the verbs dance and jump are intransitive verbs in the sentences presented, so he cannot change them into the passive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am dancing in the party.

I am jumping into the river.

You don't have objects of the verbs dance and jump to function as subjects in the passive voice. In other words, these are intransitive verbs, which cannot be transformed into the passive.

It's  rare to change prepositional verbs into the passive, For example:

The river is being jumped into by me.

However, you can change phrasal verbs (verbs consisting of more than one word) into the passive. For example:

She looks after the child (active  voice).

The child is looked after by her (passive voice).